# Status of network interface

Tags: c++, c, linux, networking

I am trying to find which network interfaces (of the local machine which has multiple IPs) are up and which are down.
Is there a C/C++ function for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See the getifaddrs man page. You can find code and man page [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getifaddrs.3.html).

Comment: It gives all the interface details. Not just the ones which are up.

Comment: You can check Tx and Rx packets.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/proc/net/` see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) for more. And also `/sys/class/net/`

Answer (score 0):

you can use GETIFADDRS(3) function creates a linked list of structures describing the network interfaces of the local system, and stores the address of the first item of the list in *ifap.

after getting all the IPs you can use ping to check whether IP is up or down

```
if ( system("ping x.x.x.x ") == 0)
{
    doSomthing();
}
```